# How do I create one user without key authentication?

Tags: ssh, password, security, authentication

I've completed the following steps:

1. I have configured Ubuntu server with Key authentication and it is working fine.
2. I have disabled password authentication for key authentication to work.
3. The server is always accessed via remote terminals or putty.

Now all user accounts are able to log in with the authentication key and pass phrase, but now I want to create only one new user without key authentication. So how should I go about it?

On the other hand, this should not hamper other users who are using key authentication.

Comment: I think what you're running into is the issue of using key based auth only. The only way I know of to allow non-key-auth is with passwords, or Kerberos stuff (which can be tricky to set up). By enabling key-only auth, you've effectively prevented non-key-auth from working.

Comment: Yes non-key auth is completely disabled and not working, it is tested.

Comment: You should not [SSH login without password](http://namhuy.net/2433/ssh-login-without-password.html) to a root user, very dangerous. You should ssh to a normal user and use su to become root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that you want to permit a particular user to use a password when nobody else can, add the following to the bottom of your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Match User rishee
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
```

Then restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Do you mean `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`?  Also, what does this line do?

Comment: Yeah I did. Fixed, thanks. `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` permits the server to prompt the user interactively. For example with a password.